# The metrics of kubectl top nodes is not correct?

Tags: kubernetes

I try to get CPU/Memory usage of the k8s Cluster Nodes via `metrics-server API`, but I found the returned values of `metrics-server` is lower than actual used CPU/Memory.

The output of kubectl top command : `kubectl top nodes`

[image]

The following is the output of the **free** command, from which you could see the memory usage is great than 90%.

[image]

Why the difference is so high?

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl top nodes` is reflecting the actual usage of your Kubernetes Nodes.

For example:

Your node has **60GB** memory and you actually use **30GB** so it will be 50% of usage.

But you can request for example:

**100 MB** and have a limit **200MB** memory.

This doesn't mean you only consume 0.16% (100 / 60000) memory, but the amount of your configuration.

Comment: Could u expalin in more details ? I'm still confused about your answer.

Comment: I cannot understand how this answers the original question. I am facing the same problem (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621512/cannot-find-memory-usage-in-kubernetes-cluster-node) and actually cannot find where all this memory usage goes. @zulv did you actually resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old topic, but I think the problem is still remaining.

To answer simply, the `kubectl top` command shows ONLY the actual resource usage, and it is not related to the request/limits configurations in your manifests.

for example:

you could obtain a 400m:1Gi (cpu/memory) usage for a specifique node while total requests/limits are 1.5:4Gi (cpu/memory).

You will observe enougth available resources to schedule but actually it will not work.

requests/limits are impacting directly node resources (resources reservation) but it does not means they are completly used (what `kubectl top nodes` is showing).